# Hibernate: Unable to locate persister integracion.entidades.Bodega

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Good evening guys!

Context: As i said in my first question (two days ago) i new with Hibernate.
In the last question the people adviced me to used Maven to work better with the dependancy. I did it and i'm pleased.

I think that i have done (almost) all what i have to do to do work a Hibernate project. The problem that i have encountered is that i dont get to persist all the entities.

The console says me that:

```
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.5.Final}
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/vinoteca]
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Tue Dec 20 00:21:34 CET 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
dic 20, 2016 12:21:34 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
dic 20, 2016 12:21:35 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
dic 20, 2016 12:21:35 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/vinoteca]
dic 20, 2016 12:21:35 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
dic 20, 2016 12:21:35 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
dic 20, 2016 12:21:35 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Tue Dec 20 00:21:35 CET 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
dic 20, 2016 12:21:35 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: integracion.entidades.Bodega
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:637)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2920)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1800(SessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2671)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2657)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1185)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1058)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.get(Unknown Source)
    at integracion.dao.GenericDAOImpl.get(GenericDAOImpl.java:48)
    at negocio.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

And my entities are these:

```
package integracion.entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

@DynamicUpdate
@Table(appliesTo = "bodega")
public class Bodega implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bodega",cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Vino> vinos;

    public Bodega(){

    }

    public Bodega(int id, String nombre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


}


package integracion.entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;


@DynamicUpdate
@Table(appliesTo = "Denominacion")
public class Denominacion implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;

    public Denominacion(){

    }

    public Denominacion(int id, String nombre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}

package integracion.entidades;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

@DynamicUpdate
@Table(appliesTo = "vino")
public class Vino implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_bodega")
    private int id_bodega;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_denominacion")
    private int id_denominacion;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="anho")
    private int anho;

    /*
     * <many-to-one name="bodega">
            <column name="id_bodega" />
        </many-to-one>
     */

    public Vino(){

    }

    public Vino(int id, int id_bodega, int id_denominacion, String nombre, int anho) {
        this.id = id;
        this.id_bodega = id_bodega;
        this.id_denominacion = id_denominacion;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.anho = anho;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId_bodega() {
        return id_bodega;
    }

    public void setId_bodega(int id_bodega) {
        this.id_bodega = id_bodega;
    }

    public int getId_denominacion() {
        return id_denominacion;
    }

    public void setId_denominacion(int id_denominacion) {
        this.id_denominacion = id_denominacion;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getAnho() {
        return anho;
    }

    public void setAnho(int anho) {
        this.anho = anho;
    }

}
```

And my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/vinoteca</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="src.main.java.integracion.entidades.Bodega.java"/>
    <mapping class="src.main.java.integracion.entidades.Denominacion.java"/>
    <mapping class="src.main.java.integracion.entidades.Vino.java"/>


  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here i have the tree project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2n1u.jpg

I have 2 theories:

First, it could be the hibernate.cfg.xml the problem cause (maybe) the paths of the mapping class tag are wrong..

Second, maybe the annotation entities are wrong because I could have made a mistake writing the relation(1:1, 1:n, n:N)..

Guys, all the help you give me i thank you!

regards!

Comment: The class names are just `integracion.entidades.Bodega`. The `src/main/java` isn't part of the class name, and neither is the source extension `.java`.

Comment: And as long as you're using annotations in the class, add `@Entity` and don't list them all in XML.

Comment: are you saying that i have to add @Entity in the class and delete zmapping class="..."/>

Comment: ?? I have seen that Entity is deprecated :S

Comment: Not that you *have* to, but there's no good reason to have part of your setup in annotations and part in XML.

Comment: You probably had the wrong annotation; you want `javax.persistence.Entity`. (Same for `Table`.)

Comment: you are right, i changed that but it doesnt work still..

Comment: that its sure that the problem is in the annotation of the .java, because i deleted all references to the entities in the xml. Could be the error maybe in the foreing keys of the MySQL tables? coudl have i to drop these?